# Wordpress dockerfile error

Tags: wordpress, docker

estoy intentando instalar Wordpress en docker, ya se supone que tengo mysql corriendo en el puerto 3306

aqui foto del estado de docker

[image: estado de docker]

y por acá el dockerfile que estoy utilizando:           `version:'3.1'`

```
`services:`  
 `adminer:
   image: adminer
   restart: always
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"`  

`db:
  image: mysql
  volumes:
   - wptut:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password`  

`wordpress:
  build: ./wordpress
  volumes:
   - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
  ports:
   - 8080:8080`

`volumes:
  wptut:`
```

me dice que el puerto que estoy usando ya está en uso, pero le estoy apuntando al 8080 de my sql. en la configuración del docker compose

Answer (score 0):

El error se dá porque estás tratando de enviar la salida de dos contenedores al mismo puerto de tu computadora

```
services:  
    adminer:
       image: adminer
       restart: always
       ports:
         - "8080:8080" #aquí estás enviando el puerto 8080 del contenedor al 8080 de tu máquina

    db:
      image: mysql
      volumes:
       - wptut:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

    wordpress:
      build: ./wordpress
      volumes:
       - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      ports:
       - 8080:8080 #aquí también estás enviando el puerto 8080 del contenedor al 8080 de tu máquina

    volumes:
      wptut:
```

Si quieres conectar los dos contenedores, sería algo así:

```
site:
  build: apache
  ports :
   - "8080:80"
  volumes:
   - ./www:/var/www/html/
  links:
   - database

database:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
   - "3333:3306"
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=basededatos
   - MYSQL_USER=usuario_wp
   - MYSQL_PASSWORD=clave_wp
  volumes:
   - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Para que esta configuración te funcione deberías agregar otro archivo en el mismo directorio llamado Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mysqli

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN a2enmod headers

RUN a2enmod expires
```

También debes crear una carpeta llamada www y allí poner el instalador de wordpress